# Redirect tested app taffic

Tags: arp, arp-poisoning

I need to perform some tests on an Android app which is connecting to REST server. unfortunatelly I can't currently connect to it test server, so I thought I'd start the web service on my computer and make my app believe its address is actual production server. To redirect this traffic I've tried to spoof the arp table on my phone with:

```
# arpspoof -i wlaninterface -t 192.168.2.2 1.2.3.4
```

Where `192.168.2.2` is the phone's IP, `1.2.3.4` is my remote server ip and my computer is under, say, `192.168.2.3`. I have my net server up and running and I can connect to it through phone's browser on `192.168.2.3` but not on the `1.2.3.4`. The same happens when I use the tested app on the phone. What can I do in the ad-hoc environment (I can't recompile anything, setup a real server etc.)?